# Why Flask pytest wont post data within app?

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I'm trying to test the following app:

```
import os
import json
import pytest
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify


def create_app(test_config=None):

    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    if test_config is None:
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        app.config['TESTING'] = True

    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    @app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
    def predict():
        p = (request.get_json()) * 2
        try:
            return jsonify({'status': 200, 'message': 'ok', 'data': p})
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({'status': 400, 'message': str(e)}), 400

    return app


@pytest.fixture
def client():
    app = create_app()
    app.config["TESTING"] = True
    app.testing = True
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client


def test_predict(client):
    response = client.post('/predict', data=json.dumps({'res': 3}))
    data = json.loads(response.get_data(as_text=True))
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert data['data'] == 6
```

When I'm running the following command:

```
pytest
```

Im getting the following error:

```
FAILED test_flask_testing.py::test_predict - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

It seems like my post request won't pass data to the app, what's wrong with my post request?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is being passed, but I don't understand what you are trying to do with this line:

`p = (request.get_json()) * 2`

Did two small changes, so the tests now are passing:

```
@@ -20,7 +20,7 @@ def create_app(test_config=None):

     @app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
     def predict():
-        p = (request.get_json()) * 2
+        p = request.get_data()
         try:
             return jsonify({'status': 200, 'message': 'ok', 'data': p})
         except Exception as e:
@@ -42,4 +42,4 @@ def test_predict(client):
     response = client.post('/predict', data=json.dumps({'res': 3}))
     data = json.loads(response.get_data(as_text=True))
     assert response.status_code == 200
-    assert data['data'] == 6
+    assert data['data'] == '{"res": 3}'
```

If you are trying to receive the incoming data as json, then you need to run the post like this:

```
response = client.post('/predict', json={'res': 3})
```

Then you need to parse as json:

```
    @app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
    def predict():
        p = request.get_json()
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ramon, passing these tests is all I needed!